# How reload image after resize in IE8?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a tag display image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->file; ?>" id="target" name="target"   />
```

I have 1 button submit resize image:
I run on googlechrome or firefox, after resize : img  will display new image, 
But i run on IE: img still display old image.
Why? How reload image after resize in IE8?

Comment: after resize rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add something in url after a filename
for example `<img src="path_to/file_name.jpg?hash_1389778842">`
it seems to be happens due to browser side caching